# XML - DTD Issue

Tags: xml, dtd

I am trying to apply DTD to a XML Document(I am new to XML). I am getting the following errors in the code. Also is there a better way apart from this to apply DTD?

```
<!DOCTYPE chat [
<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
]>

<chat>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
</chat>
```

Error

> Element type "chat" must be declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parth - Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE chat [
<!ELEMENT chat (note*)>
<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Can you explain why the line you added was needed?

Comment: For every element you need to define what are its child and the number of occurrences.

Comment: Okay. That helped. Thanks